# how to create a "random quotes" page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i would like to create a page in my site where you get, every time you access to it, a random quote, and if you press the random button the quote changes( without leaving the page ) i don't know where to start, if with use the echo command or with require and store everything with mysql... I don't know, as you can tell i'm not that good with php so i was wondering if you can help me... (also i'm not english and i think this is the only way to get help so don't be rude with your answers!)

Comment: ever heard of Ajax? MySQL? and what you have done so far. Show us !

Comment: yeah but i don't know how anything about it so i asked for help... i thought php would be ok...

Comment: You're going to want to look into using JavaScript and AJAX to retrieve the random quotes from the database.  You can use PHP to do the query from your database and AJAX to return the values to your site.  This site is not for getting code but helping you debug it.  Do a little research and then post problems you're having with your code.

Comment: yeah i know but i'm having some problems searching for the right thing... i can't find any results...

Comment: He just gave you everything you need to search. Use google. Be more cerebral about your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using a list of only a few pre-defined static quotes you could store them in an array:

```
$quoteList = array(
    "quote one", 
    "quote two", 
    "quote three", 
    "quote four"
);
```

Then use a random number generator to select the array index and echo it, for example:

```
echo $quoteList[mt_rand(0, count($quoteList)-1)];
```

This would echo a random quote from the list each time the page was accessed.

If you are looking to use a large number of quotes then a database or formatted text file (JSON or XML) may be a better way to store them.

If you want to generate a quote of random characters let me know and I will put up an example of that.

Comment: does anyone know where I can get mysql databse of quotes or csv file to import into phpmyadmin. I'm working on creating a database of quotes